# Optimization query for DataFrame Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I try create DataFrame from Hive table. But I bad work with Spark API.

I need help to optimize the query in method `getLastSession`, make two tasks into one task for spark:

```
val pathTable = new File("/src/test/spark-warehouse/test_db.db/test_table").getAbsolutePath
val path      = new Path(s"$pathTable${if(onlyPartition) s"/name_process=$processName" else ""}").toString
val df        = spark.read.parquet(path)


def getLastSession: Dataset[Row] = {
  val lastTime        = df.select(max(col("time_write"))).collect()(0)(0).toString
  val lastSession     = df.select(col("id_session")).where(col("time_write") === lastTime).collect()(0)(0).toString
  val dfByLastSession = df.filter(col("id_session") === lastSession)

  dfByLastSession.show()
  /*
  +----------+----------------+------------------+-------+
  |id_session|      time_write|               key|  value|
  +----------+----------------+------------------+-------+
  |alskdfksjd|1639950466414000|schema2.table2.csv|Failure|

  */
  dfByLastSession
}
```

PS. My Source Table (for example):

| name_process | id_session | time_write | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OtherClass | jsdfsadfsf | 43434883477 | schema0.table0.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | jksdfkjhka | 23212123323 | schema1.table1.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | alskdfksjd | 23343212234 | schema2.table2.csv | Failure |
| ExternalClass | sdfjkhsdfd | 34455453434 | schema3.table3.csv | Success |

Comment: @blackbishop, No. I'm trying to remove the "lastTime" and "lastSession" variables. So that all operations with the DataFrame occur in one approach in the variable "dfByLastSession"

Comment: My current method working correctly. I just try optimize query for spark.

Comment: You want to get the all rows corresponding to the `id_session` having most recent `time_write`, true?

Comment: @blackbishop, yes, is this true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` with Window like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val dfByLastSession = df.withColumn(
  "rn", 
  row_number().over(Window.orderBy(desc("time_write")))
).filter("rn=1").drop("rn")
    
dfByLastSession.show()
```

However, as you do not partition by any field maybe it can degrade performances.

Another thing you can change in your code, is using struct ordering to get the `id_session` associated with most recent `time_write` with one query:

```
val lastSession = df.select(max(struct(col("time_write"), col("id_session")))("id_session")).first.getString(0)

val dfByLastSession = df.filter(col("id_session") === lastSession)
```

Comment: It looks very good. Thank you for helping me. I will definitely get acquainted with the windows in spark.